# Is this possible to create GTM.js server-side logic?

Tags: c#, google-tag-manager

Im using gtm.js to track some data into my site. This is front-end part. But I need to create server-side logic(.NET) to track my data. I can;t find any information on the Google guide about server-side. Please, tell me is this possible and maybe some examples. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

GTM is a client-side Javascript injector. It's also not a tracking/analytics software, although it can be used to deploy such software.

If you want to track information to Google Analytics you can use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/), a language agnostic protocol that can be used in any language that can issue http requests.

If you need to trigger other tags from the server a service like https://segment.com/ might help you (comes for a fee. I am not affiliated or anything).

**Update Feb 2020**: Google has announced a closed beta for server-side tracking, where you run a container in a cloud environment that then distributes the requests. Simo Ahava has a little info in his twitter feed: https://twitter.com/SimoAhava/status/1222459714614841346. This is not yet a production feature.

Answer (score 1):

GTM runs only on the front end (meaning on the client's browser side). But, as I can't determine based on your question what you are trying to accomplish, I can say that you can put some information in the dataLayer in the backend and then use that info on the frontend and manipulate with it in the GTM, before sending it further to any other scripts or tracking engines.